# Android - ListView with Buttons

Tags: android, listview, button

I have a ListViewwith (the width is fill_parent) several buttons on it. The button contains an icon on the left and the text on the right. The problem is that whenever I put my finger on the button, the green background only covers up to the length of your text. Is there a let the green color cover the whole button?

Suppose this is a button in the text view, where @ is the icon and `text` is the text.

```
[@ text     ]
```

When I move my finger on the button, only this much is covered by green:

```
[#####|     ]
```

Comment: Does your button image have transparent background?

Comment: How do you implement the icon and text added in the button, With an imageview and a textview? if that, you can set the selector of the iamgeview and the textview to null, so that only the button can response your press.

Comment: Yes. The background is transparent. I used SimpleAdapter and put ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> and .put the text and image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use that as a means to achieve the icon / text on a button.

Try something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/descriptiveName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/btnIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/img" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/btnText" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="text"
    android:textColor="#6B6B6B"/>
```

get a reference to the LinearLayout the same way you would a button and you can set onClick Listeners for it in the same way too.

You can add a background to the LinearLayout and make it a selector so that it will look visually like a button too.